# How to Automatic Update The Website Which is Hosted in Raspberry Pi Using Git?

Tags: html, git, python-2.7, github, raspberry-pi3

Concept :

=>I have raspberry pi 3 B+ and installed apache2 web server which is running on port:80.

=>In /var/www/html/A/* here my lite weight website hosted.

=>I am able to access this website by typing "192.168.1.1:80" in chrome web browser.

Requirement :

- I want to run a abc.py file from the html page which is running on
  web browser.
- How to handle the condition-
  a. at the time of cloning the internet connection is lost
  b. at the time of cloning the device suddenly switched off.
- How to recover the code when raspberry pi again boot and internet connection is not available.
- Is there any other secure and safe alternative for these functionalities ?

Comment: Can you show us your work so far?

Comment: I have written a python script named "abc.py"

Comment: I have written a python script named "abc.py" in that i have written the git command. git pull origin master only simple script to pull the changes from the git to raspberry pi. abc.py also present in /var/www/html/A/* here. when running the python script using => sudo python abc.py then it taking the pull from git. But i want to run this abc.py file from the html page using web browser.

Comment: In order for running python script over web browser, your code need to be able to hand http requests, and there are many frameworks can do that, such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hcheung Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

By using the PHP and cgi-bin i am able to run the python script from the ui button click.